# The number of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I want to know whether the answer of Q49 is correct or wrong.

In the textbook, the answer is: A((BC)D)

BC: 10x40x50=20,000

(BC)D): 10x50x30=15,000

A((BC)D): 30x10x30=9,000

Total number of multiplication: 44,000

I found that if ((BC)D)A then 10x30x10=3,000

Thus the total number of multiplication is 38,000. It is smaller than the answer.

So, I think the answer is incorrect.

Am I correct?

Comment: The problem is that the result of $B C D A$ is different from $A B C D$. Matrix product is  not commutative.

Comment: Yes I understand it, but sadly that theorem does not give any help on solving my problem…

Comment: There are only 3 products in $A B C D$. It gives only 6 different ways of computing the result. You can count the number of operations in each of the 6 ways.

Comment: I’m sorry but I do not understand your explanation. What I want to know is whether the answer of the textbook is correct or wrong.

Comment: Please transcribe the screenshot, MathJax it and provide the source.

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the ways of computing the result

```
A(B(CD))
A((BC)D)
(AB)(CD)
(A(BC))D
((AB)C)D
```

for each way, compute the number of operations. You are not allowed to change the order of the matrices because matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: Why ((BC)D)A is not allowed? ((BC)D) = 10x30 and A=30x10. So why not 10x30x10 which is ((BC)D)A?

Comment: @Eric It isn't allowed because it gives a different result in general. Here $BCDA$ is a 10x10 matrix while $ABCD$ is a 30x30 matrix. It is not interesting to have a faster method that produces a different result. Even when the sizes are the same, the results are different in general.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for your explanation!! I should have read the question more carefully…